# Datatables - Loading all the data from server, but rendering part of it in datatables

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I have a table on one of my client's website, with more than 1500 rows, that pulls the data from SQL Server. And i am using DATATABLES to render the data.

The problem is, while i first started the project, i never thought that i would need AJAX or "Server Side Processing". So i directly pulled all the data to an HTML. As I had only 100-200 rows to show.

But now, i have more than 1500 rows, and the page loads very slow. I know that datatables can handle more, but i used almost every feature of datatables to impress my customer. Meaning a lot of JavaScript code lines to load, such as, resizing functions, custom searches, exporting tables, child rows, automatically adding and removing css classes, createdCell functions and more.

To put it short, it tooks 3 seconds to perform the SQL Query, but 25 seconds to render the data.

> What i would really like to do is: to load all the data (1500 rows) from the server, as it tooks 3 seconds. And render only 100 of them (25 per page x 4). And render the rest later.

How can i overcome this issue? Here is my JS code that handles the datatables:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

// Calculating table height
var calcDataTableHeight = function() {
    h = $('#sidebar-wrapper').height() - 120;
    return h;
};

    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });

    $('#tablo tfoot th').not(":eq(0)").each(function () {
      var title = $('#tablo tfoot th').eq($(this).index()).text();
      $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
    });

    var defaultOptions =  {
    "initComplete": function () {
                var api = this.api();
                api.$('td').not(":eq(0)").dblclick( function () {
                    api.search( jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string(this.innerHTML) ).draw();
                    $('#clearf').addClass('filtrevar');
                } );
            },
    "columnDefs": [
        {
        "targets": [0],
        "width": "10"
        },
        {
        "targets": [1],
        "width": "80",
        "sType": "date-uk"
        },
        {
        "targets": [2],
        "width": "80"
        },
        {
        "targets": [3],
        "width": "40",
        "visible": false
        },
        {
        "targets": [4],
        "width": "200"
        },
        {
        "targets": [5],
        "width": "200"
        },
        {
        "targets": [6],
        "width": "80",
        "visible": false
        },
        {
        "targets": [7],
        "width": "80"
        },
        {
        "targets": [8],
        "width": "120"
        },
        {
        "targets": [11],
        "width": "80",
        "visible": false
        },
        {
        "targets": [16],
        "width": "80"
        },
        {
        "targets": [17],
        "width": "80",
        "visible": false
        },
        {
        "targets": [18],
        "width": "110",
        "visible": false
        },
        {
        "width": "90",
        "targets": [9],
            createdCell: function ( cell, cellData, rowData ) {
                if(parseInt(cellData) > 0) {
                  $(cell).html('<h5 style=" margin: 0px;"><span class="label label-success">'+cellData+'</span></h5>');
                } else {
                  $(cell).html('<h5 style=" margin: 0px;"><span class="label label-default">'+cellData+'</span></h5>');
                }
            }
        },
        {
        "width": "90",
        "targets": [10],
            createdCell: function ( cell, cellData, rowData ) {
                if(parseInt(cellData) > 0) {
                  $(cell).html('<h5 style=" margin: 0px;"><span class="label label-primary">'+cellData+'</span></h5>');
                } else {
                  $(cell).html('<h5 style=" margin: 0px;"><span class="label label-default">'+cellData+'</span></h5>');
                }
            }
        },
        {
        "width": "90",
        "targets": [12],
            createdCell: function ( cell, cellData, rowData ) {
                if(parseInt(cellData) > 0) {
                  $(cell).html('<h5 style=" margin: 0px;"><span class="label label-info">'+cellData+'</span></h5>');
                } else {
                  $(cell).html('<h5 style=" margin: 0px;"><span class="label label-default">'+cellData+'</span></h5>');
                }
            }
        },
        {
        "width": "90",
        "targets": [13],
            createdCell: function ( cell, cellData, rowData ) {
                if(parseInt(cellData) > 0) {
                  $(cell).html('<h5 style=" margin: 0px;"><span class="label label-warning">'+cellData+'</span></h5>');
                } else {
                  $(cell).html('<h5 style=" margin: 0px;"><span class="label label-default">'+cellData+'</span></h5>');
                }
            }
        },
        {
        "width": "130",
        "targets": [14],
            createdCell: function ( cell, cellData, rowData ) {
                if(parseInt(cellData) > 0) {
                  $(cell).html('<h5 style=" margin: 0px;"><span class="label label-danger">'+cellData+'</span></h5>');
                } else {
                  $(cell).html('<h5 style=" margin: 0px;"><span class="label label-default">'+cellData+'</span></h5>');
                }
            }
        },
        {
        "width": "90",
        "targets": [15],
            createdCell: function ( cell, cellData, rowData ) {
                if(parseInt(cellData) > 0) {
                  $(cell).html('<h5 style=" margin: 0px;"><span class="label label-primary">'+cellData+'</span></h5>');
                } else {
                  $(cell).html('<h5 style=" margin: 0px;"><span class="label label-default">'+cellData+'</span></h5>');
                }
            }
        },
    ],    
    "scrollX": true,
    "sScrollY": calcDataTableHeight(),
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "Tümü"]],
    "bInfo" : false,
    "language": {
        "lengthMenu": "_MENU_",
        "zeroRecords": "Kayıt Bulunamadı",
        "info": "Toplam _TOTAL_ kayıttan, _START_ ve _END_ arası gösteriliyor.",
        "infoEmpty": "Herhangi bir kayıt yok.",
        "infoFiltered": "(_MAX_ toplam kayıttan filtrelenenler gösterilmektedir.)",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "İlk",
            "previous": "Önceki",
            "next": "Sonraki",
            "last": "Son"
            },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending": ": Azalan Sırada",
            "sSortDescending": ": Artan Sırada"
            },
        "sLoadingRecords": "Kayıtlar Yükleniyor...",
        "sProcessing": "Lütfen Bekleyin...",
        "search": '_INPUT_',
        "searchPlaceholder": "        Arama Yapın...",
        "orderCellsTop": true,
        "buttons": {
            "copyTitle": "Panoya Kopyalandı",
            "copySuccess": {
                "_": '%d satır kopyalandı',
                "1": '1 satır kopyalandı'
            }
        }
    }
    };

defaultOptions.sScrollY = calcDataTableHeight();
var table = $('#tablo').DataTable(defaultOptions);

//** Secilen satırı renklendirmek için
$('#tablo tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    } );
 
    $('#button').click( function () {
        table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );
    } );


    /* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
    function format(value) {
          return '<div id="childtr">' + value + '</div>';
      }
     
// Event listener - click veya diğer fonksiyonlar için
      $('#tablo').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
          var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
          var row = table.row(tr);

          if (row.child.isShown()) {
              row.child.hide();
              tr.removeClass('shown');
          } else {
              row.child(format(tr.data('child-value'))).show();
              tr.addClass('shown');
          }
      });


    // Aramayı Yap
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;
 
        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string( this.value ) )
                    .draw();
                        var icerik = $(this).val().length;
                        if (icerik == 0) {
                            $('#clearf').removeClass('filtrevar');    
                        } else {
                            $('#clearf').addClass('filtrevar');
                        }
            }
        } );
    } );

// Genel Arama
$('#tablo_filter input').attr('id', 'globalAra');
$('#tablo_filter input').keyup(function() {
  table
    .search(
      jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string(this.value)
    )
    .draw();
    var icerik = $('#globalAra').val().length;
    if (icerik == 0) {
        $('#clearf').removeClass('filtrevar');    
    } else {
        $('#clearf').addClass('filtrevar');
    }
});


// Kaydet Butonlari
var kaydedin = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, {
"buttons": [
    {
            "extend": "excelHtml5",
            "text": "Excel'e Kaydet",
            "class": "excel"
        },
    {
            "extend": "pdfHtml5",
            "text": "PDF Kaydet",
            "class": "pdf",
            "orientation": 'landscape'
        },
    {
            "extend": "copyHtml5",
            "text": "Panoya Kopyala",
            "class": "copy"
        }
    ]
});
kaydedin.container().appendTo('#sol-menu-tablo-kaydet');


var solsutunlar = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, {
"buttons": [
     {
         "extend": 'colvis',
         "text": '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" aria-hidden="true"> </span> Sütunları Aç / Kapat',
         "collectionLayout": 'fixed three-column'
     }
    ]
});
solsutunlar.container().appendTo('#sol-menu-sutunlar');

var solgorunum = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, {
"buttons": [
         {
            "text": '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet" aria-hidden="true"> </span> <span id="gorunum-deg">Standart Görünüme Geç</span>',
            "className": 'koyu',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                table.rows().every( function () {
                    this.child.hide();
                    this.nodes().to$().removeClass('shown');
                });
                var zozo =  table.column( 0 ).visible();
                if (zozo) {
                    table.column( 0 ).visible( false, false );
                    table.column( 3 ).visible( true, true );
                    table.column( 6 ).visible( true, true );
                    table.column( 11 ).visible( true, true );
                    table.column( 17 ).visible( true, true );
                    table.column( 18 ).visible( true, true );
                    table.columns.adjust().draw( true );
                } else if (!zozo) {
                    table.column( 0 ).visible( true, true );
                    table.column( 3 ).visible( false, false );
                    table.column( 6 ).visible( false, false );
                    table.column( 11 ).visible( false, false );
                    table.column( 17 ).visible( false, false );
                    table.column( 18 ).visible( false, false );
                    table.columns.adjust().draw( true );
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
solgorunum.container().appendTo('#sol-menu-gorunum');

$("#sag-ust-pagination").append($(".dataTables_paginate"));
$("#sol-ust-ara").append($(".dataTables_filter"));
$("#sol-ust-length").append($(".dataTables_length"));

//Pre loader ve Tablo Yüksekliği
$(window).load(function() {
        // Animate loader off screen
        $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
        $('div.dataTables_scrollBody').css('min-height',calcDataTableHeight());
    });


// Tüm filtreleri temizleme

    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;
 
        $('#clearf').on( 'click', function () {
        $('input[type=search]').val('');
        $('input[type=text]').val('');
        
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search("")
                .draw();
        $('#clearf').removeClass('filtrevar');       
        }
        
        $("#tablo").DataTable().search("").draw();

        } );
    } );

/* TARİH SORT ETMEK İÇİN */

jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
"date-uk-pre": function ( a ) {
    var ukDatea = a.split('.');
    return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
},

"date-uk-asc": function ( a, b ) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
},

"date-uk-desc": function ( a, b ) {
    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
}
} );


// Türkçe Karakter Sorunu
jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string = function ( data ) {
    return ! data ?
        '' :
        typeof data === 'string' ?
            data
                .replace(/i/g, 'İ')
                .replace(/ı/g, 'I') :
            data;
};


// Full Screen için
$('#ful').click(function(){
var i = document.body;

// full screen
if (i.requestFullscreen) {
    i.requestFullscreen();
} else if (i.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    i.webkitRequestFullscreen();
} else if (i.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    i.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (i.msRequestFullscreen) {
    i.msRequestFullscreen();
}
if((window.fullScreen) || (window.innerWidth == screen.width && window.innerHeight == screen.height)) {
if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
} else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
} else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
} else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
    document.msExitFullscreen();
}
}

});

// Resize olduğunda tekrar boy hesabı yapıyor.
$(window).resize(function(){  
    $('div.dataTables_scrollBody').css('max-height',calcDataTableHeight());
    table.draw();
});


});
```

And here is a screenshot of Chrome Performance:

[image]

> Note that i do not have time and resource to change the whole architecture, such as "Server Side Processing" or use AJAX.
>
> EDIT: I realized that there is a part of the code that slows down the whole process. I now have no problems at all. While i still wonder if there is a way to render part of the HTML though.

Comment: use pagination method to limit the data

Comment: @Jana thx. But i already do that. While i solved my problem, the question remains as i am curious if there is a way not to render all of the data. And your answer does not do that. Thx anyway.